# Only 50 questions in a 30 day period

Tags: support, monthly-question-limit

I have not asked 50 questions in the last 30 days but every time I try and ask a question on the main site, I get this error.  What is going on?  A friend who has only asked one question in his life is getting the same error.

Comment: Do you share an IP address?

Comment: I guess so, I use Stackoverflow from work.

Comment: I seeeeeeeee, so it's not based on username but IP address.  That's a bit restrictive.

Comment: Remember that there are *some users* who try to get around this particular limit by using different IP addresses. That's one reason this filter is in place.

Comment: My grandfather used to have a saying "Curiosity killed the cat."

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [question history tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991788/sachin-kainth?tab=questions&sort=newest) on your user page, you have asked 49 questions in that last 30 days that *I* can see ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381990/expand-not-working) was asked on 30 April 2012 and you have 48 listed after that).

If you even have *one* deleted question, that would put you at the limit (since deleted questions count towards the limit).

Comment: I guess this means I am a big ignoramus :-)

Comment: @SachinKainth Haha, nope - I wouldn't say that.  Everyone makes mistakes =)